# Is it possible to add a logo to the desktop Lync client

Tags: lync-2010, lync

Is it possible to use the Lync 2010 SDK to add a company logo into the desktop client?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're happy with the answer below, could you mark it as Accepted, to help anyone else browsing these questions? Cheers!

Comment: did you find a good solution to this requirement? Please post the answer

Comment: Nope, I didn't find a solution that did require the SDK/Development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Lync SDK doesn't give you any ability to brand the standard client. The only way you could do this would be to run Lync in [Supressed UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg436850.aspx) mode, and provide the user interface yourself - this would be a huge amount of work, as you would need to effectively re-write the entire Lync Client UI.

If you're a Win32 guru, you may be able to do something with some low-level windows API calls, but I'm not sure how feasible that would be - plus you may be on shaky ground as far as the license agreement goes